# How to troubleshoot internet down every day?

Tags: linux, debian, linux-networking, troubleshooting

Every day the server is unreachable and I need to unplug and replug it in. I cannot ping it and all web services are down. After a reboot the internet is back on again.

- There are no cronjobs
- fail2ban logs appear clean
- ufw logs appear to be clean
- Syslog is a mess and I don't know what I'm looking for

The "server" is a raspberry pi 4 with 4GB of ram running multiple docker containers and is wired to a switch. The switch itself appears to be fine also and all attached computers and servers are working properly. At first I thought it was always during the night (12am-1am), but yesterday it was a 6:30pm.

ufw rules:

```
$ sudo ufw status verbose
Status: active
Logging: on (low)
Default: deny (incoming), allow (outgoing), deny (routed)
New profiles: skip

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
Anywhere                   ALLOW IN    192.168.0.0/24            
80/tcp                     ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
443/tcp                    ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
53/tcp                     ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
22/tcp                     ALLOW IN    192.168.0.0/24            
22/tcp                     ALLOW IN    192.168.1.0/24            
80/tcp (v6)                ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)             
443/tcp (v6)               ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)             
53/tcp (v6)                ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
```

I have no idea where to look for hints on the issue or where to begin.

It seems that the server cannot ping the router while this is occurring:
[image: ping history from server to router]

Comment: Share your syslog

Comment: This may be a silly question, but have you ever looked at the console while it's down?

Comment: @tink There is no way I can access it without ssh, and never had an issue like that before so I'm kind of lost

Comment: That's a shame ... what you describe as "loss of network connectivity" may well be a full-fledged kernel panic (which you then may not see in the logs).